multi-level/recursive assignment subsasgn example in matlab
I am writing a matlab class and would like to overwrite the subasgn operator to achieve this
obj.('elem1').('subelem1').('subsubelem1')=val;

where the level of depth can vary. This type of multi-level assignment is supported in standard struct (but not in containers.Map or dictionary).
from the below link, I found examples for writing a subsasgn for only 1 subfield level, but it does not support multiple levels as struct does
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/code-patterns-for-subsref-and-subsasgn-methods.html
I am wondering if anyone can give some pointers on how to achieve this?
thanks
Update: [09/26/2024]
my sample code can be found in
https://github.com/fangq/jsonlab/blob/master/jdict.m
specifically, the subsref() function can retrieve multi-level subkeys on both MATLAB and Octave.
however, the subsasgn function can only modify the value for only one level of subfield
Update: [09/28/2024]
following the code sample suggested by rahnema1, the subsasgn in my jdict class can set subkey values at any level, and also allows to append new keys. the code can be found at
https://github.com/fangq/jsonlab/blob/ade19191e48ec3b76c362a00f696e959cd6fcdf8/jdict.m#L170-L236

The s input argument is a struct array (everything is an array in MATLAB). Each element of this array gives you one level of indexing. In your example the array would have 3 elements. You’ll have to figure out how to parse those elements to accomplish your goal. Use the debugger to look at what this s looks like under various indexing operations.

no sure what you meant by the s input. just to be clear, I am not trying to modify multiple elements in the same level, but multiple levels. subasgn already exposes the operators and operands, but the problem is that it won't allow recursive assignment.

This isn't recursive... Can you show an example of something you can achieve without subasgn which you want to be able to achieve with it? i.e. a [mcve] of your class with nested properties you want to assign to?

You already linked to the docs for subsasgn and subsref, so I figured you know about those. Both have an input argument s. Each level of indexing is an element in this array s. s(1) is the first level of indexing. s(2) is the second level of indexing. Etc. You don’t need recursion.

You've tagged this with Octave and MATLAB, are you using Octave or MATLAB? It matters because you're attracting (helpful) answers with MATLAB-specific syntax, please only use one or the other tag for something which isn't language-agnostic

@CrisLuengo, yes I use s and I can use it to retrieve multi-level subkey values with subsref without any problem. the question is how to use s and subsasgn to modify subkey values that are multiple levels down.

@Wolfie, subasgn and subsref are not matlab specific. they are supported on both matlab and octave. subsref is working perfectly on both. my question is on subasgn. I use both matlab and octave. my toolbox have been mostly written with supporting both tools in mind.

I don’t understand the problem then. You’re using subsref. subsasgn works identically, but instead of reading the value, you overwrite it. Why don’t you post your subsref code, and your attempt at subsasgn, so that we can see where your difficult is?

I updated my post to include my current implementation - https://github.com/fangq/jsonlab/blob/master/jdict.m subsref and subasgn work differently - subsref only needs to return the subkey value, but for subasgn to modify deep-level keys, it must past references instead of values down levels, which is not possible in matlab/octave.

Your indexing is into different types of other objects. As far as I can tell, your function val = subsref(obj, idxkey) can be implemented in a single line of code: val = subsref(obj.data, idxkey). Likewise for subsasgn. You're making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

By the way, I hope you're aware that obj.('elem1') is the same as obj.elem1. The parenthesis syntax is meant for when the indexing key is a variable: var = 'elem1'; obj.(var).

obj.('elem1') is the same as obj.elem1 only if obj is a struct. the jdict wrapper supports indexing struct, containers.Map and dictionary, where the latter 2 do not support .() operators and do not allow chaining of indices without using jdict.

This type of multi-level assignment can be implemented by two for loops: The forward loop and the backward loop.
In the forward step the nested structure is converted into a cell array. The value is modified and in the backward step the elements of the cell array are inserted back into their original positions in the nested structure.
Note that in the forward step the expression opcell{i}.(onekey) = []; is used to prevent unwanted copy of the elements of the nested structure.
function obj = subsasgn(obj, idxkey, otherobj)
  oplen = length(idxkey);
  opcell = cell (1, oplen + 1);
  opcell{1} = obj.data;
  obj.data = [];
  
  for i = 1:oplen
    idx = idxkey(i);
    onekey = idx.subs;
    opcell{i+1} = opcell{i}.(onekey);
    opcell{i}.(onekey) = [];
  end
  
  opcell{end}.(onekey) = otherobj;
  
  for i = oplen:-1:1
    idx = idxkey(i);
    onekey = idx.subs;
    opcell{i}.(onekey) = opcell{i+1};
  end
  
  obj.data = opcell{1};
end


The forward-loop-backward-loop approach worked beautifully! thanks a lot! I expanded your above sample and implemented most of the features I hoped to accomplish for my class, including allowing to add new keys. The code can be found at https://github.com/fangq/jsonlab/blob/ade19191e48ec3b76c362a00f696e959cd6fcdf8/jdict.m#L170-L236

If you're using MATLAB >= R2021b, your best bet is rather than mess around with subasgn like we used to have to in the bad old days, use RedefinesDot. There's a comprehensive example here https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.indexing.redefinesdot-class.html .
You will still need to do more work though, because a multi-level assignment like this will give you a vector for indexOp - but it will be much easier than using subasgn.

my class is intended to be used across both matlab and GNU Octave, for the purpose of portability, I don't want to count on matlab features that are only available in newer versions. the worst case is that I can use eval after building a recursive subasgn call string, but I would try other safer ways first, if exist, or limit the depth to 3-4 and hand-code the assignments.

subsasgn should be able to do everything, it's just a question of how convenient or otherwise it is.
